# How to override product.js file in magento

Tags: magento

I want to override the product.js file to add some extra values in some functions.I have copy the file from js/mage/adminhtml/product.js to my folder like js/myfolder/myproduct.js.How can i use the functions of the file as i try and its not working for me .When i change the object name than it will show no error but nothing happend `(Products.Gallery = Class.create()` orginal is Product.Gallery = Class.create();).
Can anyone tell me how to use all the functions of myproduct without conflicting of original funcitons.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's say you're going to override `function loadImage` from `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` in  product edit page.

Create your custom js:
`js/myfolder/myproduct.js`:

```
Product.Gallery.addMethods({
    loadImage : function(file) {
        alert('hi there');
        var image = this.getImageByFile(file);
        this.getFileElement(file, 'cell-image img').src = image.url;
        this.getFileElement(file, 'cell-image img').show();
        this.getFileElement(file, 'cell-image .place-holder').hide();
    }
});
```

Reference: http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance.html

Then in your layout xml add your custom js:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>myfolder/myproduct.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

Using this method, `function loadImage` will be overridden only if you include your `js/myfolder/myproduct.js`.

PS:
Make sure `js/myfolder/myproduct.js` is included after `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` (though it is like that by default since `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` included in `<default>` tag)

Comment: Hi ivantedja thanks for your answer. i did according to your instruction and its work for the above function but when i try to override some other function like 
 updateImages : function(file) {}
It shows me this.getFileElement(file, "cell-label input") is undefined.in the above code i added two extra fields with name link and target_window and this code work in core file but not in my custom js ??

Comment: Hi i have done by only renaming and including the js file directly in my phtml like <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);?>multibanners/myproduct.js"></script>
And it works.

Comment: in which page do you rewrite it? and which function? updateImage or updateImages?

Comment: Regarding to your function when i try to add updateImage than it generates error of this.getFileElement(file, "cell-label input") is undefined.I only inlcude this function in my js but its not work.when i copy all the functions and write down using addmethod than it generates this error , i don't know why by addmethod it through this error.Now i simply rename the js file and inlude it in phtml and it works.Did you know why it show error with addmethods ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman what Magento version do you use? So, it is working for `loadImage` but not working for `updateImage`?